# Centrar heading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um heading com a class Display-4 do bootstrap dentro de um jumbotron e não estou a conseguir centrar apenas este heading, obrigado.

```
<div class="jumbotron mt-5 pt-4">
    <h1 class="display-4 mx-auto" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #5C7D45 !important; display: inline-block;">Olá <?php echo $_SESSION['fName']; ?></h1>
```

Acho que há algo de desnecssário no código, se houver por favor avisem, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema é que vc tem que usar a classe `text-center`, para alinhar o texto no centro, e o estilo do Sublinhado vc pode por em um `<span>` por fora do texto

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <div class="jumbotron mt-5 pt-4">
        <h1 class="display-4 mx-auto text-center" >
          <span style="border-bottom: 1px solid #5C7D45 !important; display: inline-block;">Olá <?php echo $_SESSION['fName']; ?></span>
        </h1>
  </div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Hugo!

Comment: @Afonso sem problemas jovem é o fato no spam estar dentro do h1 não atrapalha a semântica